# Request on several user accounts at once

Tags: twitter

For my application I need to retrieve the number of followers of a list of Twitter accounts. It works fine so far; however I guess I'm limited to 150 calls per hour since I'm calling anonymously.

Here is, in pseudo code, the request I send:

```
foreach(user in mylist)
{
    HttpWebRequest.Create(http://twitter.com/users/show.xml?screen_name=[username]);
    retrieveNbFollowers(request.GetResponse());
}
```

Now, my question... :)  Is there a way to send that kind of request for several users at once, for example [...]/show.xml?screen_name=user1,user2,user3,etc. (which doesn't work btw). I couldn't find a solution yet... maybe it is simply not allowed by the API...

Thank you for your help

Sylvain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right idea, just the function you want is [users/lookup](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/lookup):

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id=783214,6253282
```

**EDIT**

Just realized you're doing this unauthenticated. You're going to need authentication for this call. I'd recommend an OAuth library but I'm not sure which language you're using.

Comment: .NET I think?  There's a couple libraries here: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#dotnet

Comment: Thank you very much Onteria ! I overlooked this function in the API documentation and didn't see I could request several users ... stupid me !
It now works exactly the way I want ;)
Thx !!